# Wi-Fi Direct Group Owner Frequency Band

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifi-direct, wifi

I'm currently using a Nexus 10 (2.4 GHz and 5 GHz dual band radio) to connect to a third-party peripheral device (2.4GHz single band radio) via Wi-Fi Direct. When I connect the tablet as a Client, and the peripheral device as the Group Owner (GO), the connection is made without problem since the GO determines the frequency band to use, i.e., 2.4 GHz, which is supported by both devices.

However, attempting to connect with the Nexus 10 as the GO, and the peripheral device as the client, the connection fails. I have deduced that this failure occurs because the Nexus 10, being the GO, determines the frequency band of the connection, and is attempting to use 5 GHz, which is not supported by the peripheral device.

Setting the Wi-Fi to 2.4 GHz (via the Wi-Fi Settings, Advanced tab), forces the Nexus 10 as the GO to use 2.4 GHz during the group negotiation, resulting in a successful connection to the client peripheral device.

So, I have two questions:

1). Is it possible, via the `WifiP2p` (or `wpa-supplicant`) suite of APIs to set the frequency band that should be used during group negotiation? This ought to be possible if Android devices are equipped with dual band radios.

2). Is it possible, via the `Wifi` suite of APIs, to set the Wi-Fi to use only 2.4 GHz?

Any pointers or advice appreciated.

Comment: However this could not be done through open public APIs!

Answer (score 0):

I tested create a wifi direct group on the Yoga tablet 2 pro (Android 5.0) and had the same issue. It's an old question but I can't find an any reference to it anywhere else and this is still the top Google result for this topic.

If the wifi direct group is created when the device is connected to a 5Ghz access point, then that wifi direct group will also be 5Ghz. If the group is created when there is no wifi connection active or a 2.4Ghz connection active, then the wifi direct group is 2.4Ghz.

I'm not sure what happens if the connection changes. E.g. you could try disconnecting the wifi from the access point, establishing the wifi direct group, and then reconnecting to the access point.

Comment: It seems that if you create the connection in Pdanet+ while the host device is connected to a 2.4ghz network, connect the client device and then switch the host device to a 5ghz network, the client device will stay connected. However, if you disconnect the client device, it will not be able to reconnect. If you switch the host's Wifi back to a 2.4ghz network, the client will again be able to connect. So it seems that Wifi direct negotiation is done using the frequency band of the last connected network (You're a bit off where you stated Wifi direct will use 2.4ghz if no connection is active).